# android opengl depth test fails

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I have a problem in the Android Emulator, I render a texture cube with gles 1 and in the borders show the back faces:

[image: Problem image]

My depth test setup is :

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  // Set color's clear-value to black
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);            // Set depth's clear-value to farthest
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enables depth-buffer for hidden surface removal
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);    // The type of depth testing to do
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);  // nice perspective view
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading of color
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);      // Disable dithering for better performance
```

And my perspective:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) height = 1;   // To prevent divide by zero
    float aspect = (float)width / height;

    // Set the viewport (display area) to cover the entire window
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Setup perspective projection, with aspect ratio matches viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select projection matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset projection matrix
    // Use perspective projection         
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, aspect, 0.1f, 1000.f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);  // Select model-view matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset

    // You OpenGL|ES display re-sizing code here
    // ......
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may not have enough precision in your depth buffer, so the faces are somewhat overlapping.

I would recommend to reduce your depth range if possible, either increase the near plane (say to 1), reduce the far plane. The farther apart the planes are the less precision you get for the existing range.